# good utility for viewing ANSI animations?

Tags: ansi, bbs

I've got a bunch of ANSI animations left over from my BBS days that were designed to animate correctly over 2400baud.

Does anyone know of a good windows utility that would let me view these while controlling playback speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out "[ACiD View 6 for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acidview6-win32/)".  Yes, it's *THAT* ACiD. :)